# Inserting TIME into table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert a TIME value in a table in `SQL Developer`, but I get the current month returned. I am using Date as the constraint when creating the table. Sorry for the poorly written code, I'm not familiar with SQL.

```
INSERT INTO DELIVERY(ORDER_ID, DELIVERY_ID, DELIVERY_DATE, DELIVERY_TIME)
VALUES(1, 1565412,('06/Sep/12'),(TO_DATE('16:18:14', 'hh24:mi:ss')));
```

**Output:**

`ORDER_ID DELIVERY_ID DELIVERY_DATE DELIVERY_TIME`

```
     1     1565412 06-SEP-12     01-FEB-15     
     2     8456233 24-MAR-12     01-FEB-15     
     3     8412654 21-JUN-12     01-FEB-15     
     4     1124335 03-JUN-11     01-FEB-15     
     5     7218854 30-AUG-11     01-FEB-15 `
```

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE DELIVERY (
ORDER_ID      NUMBER(7),
DELIVERY_ID   NUMBER(7) CONSTRAINT DELIVERY_ID_NN   NOT NULL,
DELIVERY_DATE DATE      CONSTRAINT DELIVERY_DATE_NN NOT NULL, 
DELIVERY_TIME DATE      CONSTRAINT DELIVERY_TIME_NN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(DELIVERY_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID)  REFERENCES ORDERS(ORDER_ID)
);
```

When I 'SELECT delivery_time FROM DELIVERY` I want to be shown the time I have inserted into the table, not the date. I don't understand why it shows me 01-FEB-15

Comment: So, what's your question? Oracle's `DATE` data type has both date and time components. When the date component is not specified, it defaults to the current date.

Comment: When I 'SELECT delivery_time FROM DELIVERY` I want to be shown the time I have inserted into the table, not the date. I don't understand why it shows me 01-FEB-15

Comment: Then format the value the way you want using `TO_CHAR()`; by default it's formatted as a date. I'm also not sure why you are attempting to store `delivery_date` and `delivery_time` as separate columns.

Comment: Thank you. You're right I'll remove one of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time is being stored ok. However, you need to put a mask on your `DELIVERY_TIME` column to display only the time. Try this query:

```
select order_id, delivery_id, delivery_date, to_char(delivery_time,'hh24:mi:ss') 
from delivery
```

You can also set your NLS settings in `SQL Developer` to display the time by default in the menu

- Tools
- Preferences
- Database
- NLS,

then set the field Date Format (this is in version 4.0.0.13, I don't know if it changes in other versions).

Comment: Ah thank you that works. So time will only be outputted if you state it in the query? Shouldn't it just be output by simply writing delivery_time in the select query?

Comment: If you use a DATE data type, yes. DATE stores the date you input up to the second. It's how you display the date or time (or both) in you query what will be affected by the date mask you use, or your NLS settings.

Comment: So is there a TIME field which will only store the time?

Comment: No, because DATE already does it. As @mustaccio said, it's pointless to have two different DATE type columns, one for date and one for time. Both will store the exact same thing.